# Animation for drawings

Tags: ios, swift, here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk

I'm wondering is there are some available animations exist for changing `MapPolyline` and `MapPolygon` on the fly".

For now, I'm able to draw both of them and edit them via `geometry` property, but without any animations:

```
let geoPolyline = try! GeoPolyline(vertices: option3Geo)
let lineColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.56, blue: 0.54, alpha: 0.63)
mapPolyline = MapPolyline(geometry: geoPolyline,
                                        widthInPixels: 30,
                                        color: lineColor)
mapView.mapScene.addMapPolyline(mapPolyline!)
// and later to update without any animations    
mapPolyline?.geometry = newPoints
```

same for polygon:

```
let geoPolygon = try! GeoPolygon(vertices: option3Geo)

let fillColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.56, blue: 0.54, alpha: 0.63)
mapPolygon = MapPolygon(geometry: geoPolygon, color: fillColor)
        
mapView.mapScene.addMapPolygon(mapPolygon!)

// later
mapPolygon.geometry = geometry
```

It would be great, if some animation can be added to this change - in my case, user change the polygon "on the fly", and without animation it looks a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, with HERE SDK 4.7.5.0, such animations are not available for MapPolyline <-> MapPolygon on SDK-side. It may be a reasonable request to add animations and maybe it's planned for a future release, but in your case, the best solution would be to apply animations on app-level. Then you have full control on the behavior you would like to see. You can either apply animations to a MapPolyline to drag them on screen, or morph between different shapes. This only requires a little bit of math. You may also look for some existing animation libraries, like [Spring](https://github.com/MengTo/Spring).

Since the HERE SDK allows to update the geometry on the next rendered frame, this could be used to set slightly modified polylines animated over time by using a display link.

Define a loop that is synchronized with the display rendering:

```
private lazy var displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self,
                                                 selector: #selector(animatorLoop))
```

Start the render loop:

```
displayLink.isPaused = false
displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .common)
```

Animate:

```
// Called periodically.
@objc private func animatorLoop() {
   // Change the geometry ... 
}
```

There is actually an HERE SDK example that makes use of this to change the zoom level over time in the [Gestures](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/navigate/ios/Gestures/Gestures/GestureMapAnimator.swift) example app. I slightly modified it above to show how it generally works.

Comment: thanks for response - yes, animation using alternative methods can be used of cause, but before doing this, I just want to be sure, that such functionality is not supported by the sdk. Thanks for response